# How to get information about a user in Evernote after authorization through OAutth?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, authorization, evernote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get information about a user in Evernote after authorization through OAutth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582236/how-to-get-information-about-a-user-in-evernote-after-authorization-through-oaut)

I'm doing a webservice authorization  through Evernote on php(use OAuth doc:http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/Authentication.php ), but I can not figure out how to get information about the user by userid(email. username, fullname).

Step by step action(Example)

**Step 1**
Sample temporary credentials request:

```
https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth?oauth_consumer_key=en_oauth_test&oauth_signature=1ca0956605acc4f2%26&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_timestamp=1288364369&oauth_nonce=d3d9446802a44259&oauth_callback=https%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%2Fsettings%2Findex.php%3Faction%3DoauthCallback
```

I get responce

```
oauth_token=en_oauth_test.12BF8802654.687474703A2F2F6C6F63616C686F73742F7E736574682F4544414D576562546573742F696E6465782E7068703F616374696F6E3D63616C6C6261636B.1FFF88DC670B03799613E5AC956B6E6D&oauth_token_secret=&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

**Step 2**

Redirect user to Evernote authorization

```
https://www.evernote.com/OAuth.action?oauth_token=en_oauth_test.12BF8802654.687474703A2F2F6C6F63616C686F73742F7E736574682F4544414D576562546573742F696E6465782E7068703F616374696F6E3D63616C6C6261636B.1FFF88DC670B03799613E5AC956B6E6D
```

If the user can get my application data profile Evernote redirect user to my callback url

```
https://example.com/auth/index.php?action=oauthCallback&oauth_token=en_oauth_test.12BF88D95B9.687474703A2F2F6C6F63616C686F73742F7E736574682F4544414D576562546573742F696E6465782E7068703F616374696F6E3D63616C6C6261636B.AEDE24F1FAFD67D267E78D27D14F01D3&oauth_verifier=0D6A636CD623302F8D69DBB8DF76D86E
```

**Step 3**

I have oauth_token and verifier token  and I create query for sample token credentials request:

```
https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth?oauth_consumer_key=en_oauth_test&oauth_signature=1ca0956605acc4f2%26&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_timestamp=1288364923&oauth_nonce=755d38e6d163e820&oauth_token=en_oauth_test.12BF8888B3F.687474703A2F2F6C6F63616C686F73742F7E736574682F4544414D576562546573742F696E6465782E7068703F616374696F6E3D63616C6C6261636B.C3118B25D0F89531A375382BEEEDD421&oauth_verifier=DF427565AF5473BBE3D85D54FB4D63A4
```

Sample token credentials response

```
oauth_token=S%3Ds4%3AU%3Da1%3AE%3D12bfd68c6b6%3AC%3D12bf8426ab8%3AP%3D7%3AA%3Den_oauth_test%3AH%3D3df9cf6c0d7bc410824c80231e64dbe1&oauth_token_secret=&edam_noteStoreUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.evernote.com%2Fedam%2Fnote%2Fshard%2Fs4&edam_userId=161
```

In this example, the OAuth token credential identifier is:

```
S=s4:U=a1:E=12bfd68c6b6:C=12bf8426ab8:P=7:A=en_oauth_test:H=3df9cf6c0d7bc410824c80231e64dbe1
```

and I have user id *&edam_userId=161*

**How do I retrieve user profile with token access and usreid?**

Can someone help.

P.S. Sorry, for my English. Only began to teach

Answer (score 2):

You can call [UserStore.getUser(accessToken)](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/UserStore.html#Fn_UserStore_getUser) to get some information about the user, including their full name. You will not be able to retrieve their email address, which is private.

Comment: Thank you!  I understand that the documentation of the data request and the user does not have. We should extract logic from evernote-php-sdk

Comment: Seth are you the author evernote-sdk for php? Can I tell you later will ask few questions about importing logic from this library?

Comment: Yes, I'm one of the authors of the Evernote SDK for PHP. Happy to chat about it.